# How to see the next few occurences of a repeated task in emacs org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have recently started using the timestamp feature of the org-mode and I have few tasks that repeat. For example:

```
* Match 

  <2020-09-09 Wed 07:00 +2w>
```

I am looking for a way to see the next few occurrences of this task. E.g. Sep 23,  Oct 7th etc. I know of the command `C-c C-o` (`org-open-at-point`) that shows entire agenda for the date but I only want to see this single task (and future occurrences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the agenda to the current buffer. Assuming you are following the convention in the manual where `C-c a` is bound to `org-agenda`, then from the buffer where your entry is located, type `C-c a` to get the agenda dispatcher, then `<` to restrict the agenda to the current buffer, then `a` to display the dily/weekly agenda. You can change the length of the displayed agenda using the normal keybindings (e.g. `v m` to change to a monthly view).

In summary, while the current buffer, type

`C-c a < a v m`

You should see the occurrences of the task in the current month. You can move forward in time with `f` (`org-agenda-later`) or backward in time with `b` (`org-agenda-earlier`). And instead of `m`, you can do `d`, `w`, `t` or `y`. Just press `v` to see all the choices. And read
the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html#Agenda-Commands) for more complete information.

BTW, if you have more than one task in the buffer, that will show you *all* of those tasks. But you can select a region, and then use `<<` to restrict to that region: so you can slim down the agenda to a single task.

EDIT: To show only the dates that have entries, you can set `org-agenda-show-all-dates` to `nil` (it is `t` by default). Its doc string says:

> Non-nil means ‘org-agenda’ shows every day in the selected range.
> When nil, only the days which actually have entries are shown.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. Is there any way to hide the days that have no events? By following above directions, I am able to see a single task and its future occurrences but since it is a bi-weekly task, there will be lot of days in between cluttering the agenda view.

Comment: Edited to address the comment.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.